# Add 'n' items to local storage (items are getting from json file)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting info from a json file, and i need to store some items on local storage.

This is my code to get the data from json file:

```
    $scope.selection = "Selecciona una categoría";

    $scope.filterAvailable = function(available){
        var filteringBy = [];

        $http.get('/app/json/file.json')
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.listOfProducts = data.data.products;

                for(var i = 0; i< $scope.listOfProducts.length; i++){
                    if($scope.listOfProducts[i].available === true && $scope.listOfProducts[i].sublevel_id === $scope.inside){
                        filteringBy.push($scope.listOfProducts[i]);
                    }
                }

                $scope.dataOnFilter = filteringBy;
        });
    }
```

And with a ng-repeat, i show the info on my html view:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="data in dataOnFilter"><a ng-click="selected(data)">{{data.name}}</a>
</ul>
```

Then, i catch the specific value and save on local storage by clicking on the `<a>` tag with the next piece of code:

```
    $scope.selected = function(y){
        $scope.dataAdd = y;

        localStorage.setItem('valid', JSON.stringify($scope.dataAdd));
    }
```

If i want to see the selected info on a modal, just have to click on another button:

```
    $scope.openCart = function(){
        $scope.myItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('valid'));

        $('#cart').modal({
            show: true
        });
    }
```

Everything is perfect if i select one item, but, if i choose another, the info are rewrited. What i need is store all the selected items in the local storage.

Someone can help me, please?

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your data as an Array instead of Object. This function add selected value to an array named collection.

```
$scope.selected = function(y) {
    $scope.dataAdd = y;

    localStorage.collection = localStorage.collection || "[]";
    var collection = JSON.parse(localStorage.collection);
    collection.push($scope.dataAdd);
    localStorage.collection = JSON.stringify(collection);
}
```